# substring after split by a separator oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, split, concatenation

Like if I have a string "123456,852369,7852159,1596357"
The out put looking for "1234,8523,7852,1596"

Requirement is....we want to collect 4 char after every ',' separator

like split, substring and again concat

```
select
  REGEXP_REPLACE('MEDA,MEDA,MEDA,MEDA,MEDA,MEDA,MEDA,MEDA,MDCB,MDCB,MDCB,MDCB,MDCB,MDCB', '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1')
from dual;
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the distinct value?
123456,852369,7852159,1596357,123489"
O/P will be 1234,8523,7852,1596  
1234 should not repeat again

Answer (score 1):

> we want to collect 4 char after every ',' separator

Here is an approach using `regexp_replace`:

```
select regexp_replace(
    '123456,852369,7852159,1596357',
    '([^,]{4})[^,]*(,|$)',
    '\1\2'
)
from dual
```

Regexp breakdown:

```
([^,]{4})    4 characters others than "," (capture that group as \1)
[^,]*        0 to n characters other than "," (no capture)
(,|$)        either character "," or the end of string (capture this as \2)
```

The function replaces each match with capture 1 (the 4 characters we want) followed by capture 2 (the separator, if there is one).

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OIK84vr1)**:

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 1234,8523,7852,1596 |

Comment: Perfect .... :)

Comment: Yes, it is working fine....one problem....if any space after ','....then we need to do trim, how?

Comment: Is it possible to get the distinct value?
123456,852369,7852159,1596357,123489"
O/P will be 1234,8523,7852,1596  
1234 should not repeat again

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to split the string, extract 4 characters and aggregate them back:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '123456,852369,7852159,1596357' from dual)
  3  select listagg(regexp_substr(col, '[^,]{4}', 1, level), ',')
  4         within group (order by level) result
  5  from test
  6  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234,8523,7852,1596

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes , this also is working, but I would prefer regexp_replace previous option because that can be use in a select query very simple

Answer (score 0):

With `REGEX_REPLACE`:

```
select regexp_replace(the_string, '(^|,)([^,]{4})[^,]*', '\1\2')
from mytable;
```

This looks for

1. the beginning of the string or the comma
2. then four characters that are not a comma
3. then any number of trailing characters that are not a comma

And only keeps

1. the beginning or the comma
2. the four characters that follow

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/efUFvKyO

Comment: Oops, now I see that my answer is almost the same as GMB's. So, sorry for not having added anything very useful here.

Comment: Yes, it is working fine....one problem....if any space after ','....then we need to do trim, how?

Comment: Is it possible to get the distinct value?
123456,852369,7852159,1596357,123489"
O/P will be 1234,8523,7852,1596  
1234 should not repeat again

Comment: For this you need another approach where you loop through the items and check for uniqueness. This can be done in a PL/SQL function or with a recursive query. With both methods you would split the string first to get an array of four-character items and then put them together again.